# What can we do to increase awareness of Community Wiki mode?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, help

I don't think I'm atypical of newer SE users in that, while I have seen incidental mention of "Community Wiki", I had to come here to find out what it actually meant (beyond the basic concept of wiki, which I was already familiar with). Might be worth having the text which suggests it include a link to an explanation of what and why.

Comment: Tooltip probably?

Comment: relevant: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Comment: OK, that blog post takes things in a different direction than I was expecting from what I'd seen...